# I can't alias def $?="type $? || echo 'varible not defined' "

Tags: command-line, alias

I want to create an alias called def that takes a varible and checks if it's defined.
If it isn't def prints 'the varible is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will print an error message if the given the name of a variable that is null or undefined:

```
def() { : "${!1:? "Variable not defined."}" ; }
```

Examples:

```
$ def PATH
$ def NONESUCH
bash: !1:  Variable not defined.
```

This function requires `bash`.

#### Explanation:

The body of the function consists of one command which is given one argument.  The command is `:` which acts like a no-operation.  The argument to that command is `"${!1:? "Variable not defined."}"`.  In `bash,` the construct `${!1}` returns the value of the variable whose name is given by `$1`, the first argument to the function. If the variable whose name is `$1` is set and not null, then `"${!1:? "Variable  not defined."}"` returns its value.  Its value is ignored by `:` because `:` is a no-op.  If the variable with that name is either unset or null, then, because of the `:?` parameter expansion construct, the given error message is returned.

#### Improved Output Format

The above function did not return *exactly* the message that you asked for.  We can fix that:

```
$ def() { ( : "${!1:? "Variable  not defined."}" ) 2>&1 | sed 's/^bash: !1:  //'; }
$ def NONESUCH
Variable not defined.
```

Or,

```
$ def() { ( : "${!1:?}" ) 2>/dev/null || echo "Variable not defined"; }
$ def NONESUCH
Variable not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (and perhaps a bit before that, but *not* as far back as 10.04 LTS), [the `bash` version in Ubuntu has been at least 4.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash). [Thus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash#comment31736775_17538964) it [supports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448624/1038860) the `-v` operator for the `test`, `[`, and `[[` [builtins](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).

If you only learn one way to test if variables are defined in bash, it should probably be the [parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) technique used in John1024's excellent answer. Even though Ubuntu systems using bash 4.1 and earlier are becoming increasingly uncommon, [10.04 still has limited server support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), and earlier versions of bash are much more common on some other GNU/Linux systems (and other Unix-like OSes).

But if you have bash 4.2 or higher, the "improved output format" from [John1024's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/524567/22949) can be further simplified to:

```bash
def() { [ -v "$1" ] || echo 'Variable not defined'; }
```

Note that if `foo` is the name of the variable you're interested in, `[ -v foo ]`--*not* `[ -v $foo ]`--tests if it's defined. In this case, I have `$1` because the first positional parameter passed to `def` will contain the name of the variable to be tested *as its value*. (The `$` in my example achieves the same additional level of [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) achieved by `!` in the `${...}` expression of [John1024's example](https://askubuntu.com/a/524567/22949).)

```bash
ek@Ilex:~$ def() { [ -v "$1" ] || echo 'Variable not defined'; }
ek@Ilex:~$ def PATH
ek@Ilex:~$ def NONESUCH
Variable not defined
```

---

Both my and [John1024's](https://askubuntu.com/a/524567/22949) `def` [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation#Computer_science) will print `Variable not defined`:

- when no variable by the name passed as the function's first argument exists
- *but also* when no first argument is passed to `def`.

That is:

```
ek@Ilex:~$ def
Variable not defined
```

If you'd prefer a separate message in that situation, you can handle the case of `def` receiving no arguments separately:

```bash
def() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'error: too few arguments' >&2
        return 1
    elif [ ! -v "$1" ]; then
        echo 'Variable not defined'
    fi
}
```

I've written that based on the idea that having `def`'s first argument exist, whether or not it names a defined variable, is considered normal operation, and not an error. In contrast, passing no arguments to `def` is an error and I've treated it as such:

- `>&2` [sends](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) the output of `echo` to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29).
- `return 1` makes `def` return with nonzero exit status, indicating failure. (This is mainly useful for when a call to `def` will appear instead a compound statement or script, though the exit status of the last command may also be checked with `echo $?`.)

  In other cases `def` will return the default exit status of 0 (unless of course there's some other error, such as `echo` being unable to write `Variable not defined` to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)).

```bash
ek@Ilex:~/source$ def NONESUCH
Variable not defined
ek@Ilex:~/source$ def
error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#ALIASES):

> In a script, aliases have very limited usefulness. It would be nice if
>   aliases could assume some of the functionality of the C preprocessor,
>   such as macro expansion, but unfortunately Bash does not expand
>   arguments within the alias body. [117] Moreover, a script fails to
>   expand an alias itself within "compound constructs," such as if/then
>   statements, loops, and functions. An added limitation is that an alias
>   will not expand recursively. Almost invariably, whatever we would like
>   an alias to do could be accomplished much more effectively with a
>   function.

This is why you should follow Eliah Kagan or John1024 answer.